# hline in tabular inside a figure

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx, subfloats

I'm trying to add a line (`\hline` or `\hdashline`) in between two rows in a 4 rows tabular, contained in a figure:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%% TITLE
\title{Title}

\author{1\\2\\{\tt\small 3}
\and4\\5\\{\tt\small 6}
}


\maketitle
\begin{figure*}

\centering
\hspace{-22pt}
% \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1em}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize}p{1.2cm}cccccc}

Input          &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\\
Output          &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a} \\ \hdashline
\rule{0pt}{10ex}
Input          &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\\
Output          &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}
&\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}    &\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-a}

\end{tabular}

\caption{More results} \label{figure:more results}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to have the line in the middle of the gap? and not sticking to the top?
Trying replacing `\rule` with `\vspace`, but it moved only the text (first column) without the figures.
Thanks.

Comment: Please extend your sniplet to a full example, your choice of class and packages might be important

Comment: Unrelated, don't use the `center` env to center inside a figure env, it introduces extra vertical spacing on top of what the figure env already provides. Normally we write `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and we drop `\end{center}`

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Comment: Unrelated 2: `\tt` and friends has been outdated since 1993! I also would not use the `times` or `epsfig`  packages anymore

Comment: Unrelated 3: drop `capt-of` that is covered by `\captionof` from the `caption` package

Comment: You could load the `booktabs` package and try `\addlinespace[1em]
\hdashline
\addlinespace[1em]
` that seems to work

Comment: Perfect, it works, open an answer and I'll accept it:)

Comment: unrelated but don't use the `epsfig` package, I wrote that as a legacy compatibility package in 1994 for documents written in the 1980s. It really shouldn't be appearing on my screen this millennium:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the `booktabs` feature `\addlinespace`.

Also `tabular*` so you don't have to bother with spaces; it just needs an educated guess for the width of the pictures.

Using `scale` is not the best way, because it depends on the original size of the pictures and guessing the right factor is generally more difficult.

In the code I commented out some obsolete packages and the ones that are not needed for the example.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

%\usepackage{mathptmx} % times is obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better
%\usepackage{epsfig} % obsolete
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{capt-of}
%\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{\footnotesize}{l} 
  cccccc
}

Input
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\\ \addlinespace
Output
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\\
 \addlinespace
 \hdashline
 \addlinespace
Input
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\\ \addlinespace
Output
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} 
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
       &\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{More results} \label{figure:more results}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Learned a lot today, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to egreg's anwer, here is a variant that uses `\adjustboxset` in combination with `\adjustimage` to avoid repeated optional arguments of the `\includegraphics` commands. To add some vertical white space between adjacent rows of images as well as around the horizontal dashed line, I used the `cellspace` package. The amount of whice space can be adjusted by changing the values of `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\adjustboxset{width=0.14\textwidth,valign=c}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\footnotesize}{l}*{6}{0c}}
Input
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a} 
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
\\ 
Output
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a} 
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
\\
 \hdashline
Input
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a} 
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
\\
Output
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a} 
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
       & \adjustimage{}{example-image-a}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{More results} \label{figure:more results}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```